# Comparing a binomial coefficient to a fraction of factorials

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients, solution-verification, factorial

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Given an integer $n \ge 3$, find an integer $x$ such that:

$${x \choose n} > \frac{x!}{\left(x-\frac{n}{3}\right)!}$$

I don't see any tricks so here's what I came up with.

$$x \ge \sqrt[\frac{2n-3}{3}]{n!}+n-1$$

Here's my thinking:

(1)  Assume: 
$${x \choose n} > \frac{x!}{\left(x - \frac{n}{3}\right)!}$$

(2)  Then:

$$x(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-n+1) > (n!)(x)(x-1)\dots\left(x-\frac{n}{3}+1\right)$$

(3)  Since $\dfrac{n}{3} < n$, it follows that:

$$\left(x-\frac{n}{3}\right)\left(x - \frac{n}{3}-1\right)\dots(x-n+1) > n!$$

(4)  Since there are $\dfrac{3n-3}{3} - \dfrac{n}{3} = \dfrac{2n-3}{3}$ terms, this is definitely true if:

$$x-n+1 \ge \sqrt[\frac{2n-3}{3}]{n!}$$

Or equivalently:

$$x \ge \sqrt[\frac{2n-3}{3}]{n!}+n - 1$$

Is there a better way to solve this?  Is there a more interesting answer to this problem?

Comment: You don't state it explicitly, but it seems you're requiring $n$ to be a multiple of $3$. Otherwise, for $\left(x - \frac{n}{3}\right)!$, you will need to use something like the gamma function to define that.

Comment: I think that the gamma function would work fine.  It doesn't strictly need to be a multiple of $3$.  It just has to be greater than the floor to be correct.   Does the gamma function result in a lower bound?

Comment: As you can see, the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) does interpolate values between the factorials quite well, so using it should not likely make much difference compared to requiring that $n$ be a multiple of $3$. However, if you choose to use this, then your statements like the RHS of $x(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-n+1) > (n!)(x)(x-1)\dots\left(x-\frac{n}{3}+1\right)$ should be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: I assume that it is divisible by $3$ to keep it simple.  I am not clear that adjusting the equation to use the gamma would improve the result.  If it does, then I am very open to using it.

Comment: Since your inequality for $x$ depends on the relatively blunt requirement that $x-n+1 \ge \sqrt[\frac{2n-3}{3}]{n!}$, and if you use the gamma function for non-integral factorial representation due to its quite smooth interpolation, your result will be be true for at least all but the smallest values of $n$ even (I haven't checked these small values of $n$ myself (e.g., $n = 1, 2$), but you may wish to) if you don't require that $n$ be divisible by $3$. As for "improving the result", that depends on what you mean by "improving", so that's something you should decide for yourself.

Comment: I think you make a great point.  I'll  use the gamma function to get a cleaner result.  I'll add the gamma version to my question as an additional note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x ≤n$ is the condition for holding relation $\big(^x_n\big)=\frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}$.
If $3|n$ and $\frac{n}{3} ≤x<n$ we may write:

$$\big(^{\frac{n}{3}}_x\big)=\frac{x!}{\frac{n}{3}!(x-\frac{n}{3})!}$$

Or:

$$\frac{x!}{(x-\frac{n}{3})!}=\frac{n}{3}!\big(^{\frac{n}{3}}_x\big)$$

Now we have to show:

$$\big(^x_n\big)>\frac{n}{3}!\big(^{\frac{n}{3}}_x\big)$$

This can be checked numerically, for example:

$n=9$, $x=9/3=3$ gives $\big(^3_9\big)=84$

$\frac{9}{3}!\big(^3_3\big)=6\frac{3!}{3!(0)!}=6$