# Is $g(x)$ a decreasing function toward a limit? If yes, what is the limit?

Tags: limits, derivatives, logarithms, gamma-function

Let:

- $f(x) = \left(\Gamma(x+1)\right)^{\left(\frac{\ln x}{x\ln x - 1.25506x}\right)} + x - 1$
- $g(x) = \dfrac{f(x)}{x}$

Is $g(x)$ a decreasing function toward a limit?  If yes, what is the limit?

I suspect that it is.  When I test out values, I am seeing that for $x \ge 17$, $g(x) < 3$ and from there, it appears to decrease toward a limit.

Here is my reasoning about the equation (please feel free to point out any mistakes, I am learning and am glad to revise):

(1)  $\dfrac{\ln x}{x \ln x - 1.25506x}$ is decreasing for $x \ge 10$ since in this case $\ln x > 2.25506$ and $x\ln x - 1.25506x > x > \ln x$

(2) Using [Stirling's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation):

$$\Gamma(x+1) \sim \sqrt{2\pi x}\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^x$$

(3)  $\Gamma(x+1)^{\left(\frac{\ln x}{x\ln x - 1.25506x}\right)} \sim \left(\sqrt{2\pi x}\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^x\right)^{\frac{\ln x}{x}}$

(4)  Would it be correct to assume that this approximates to:

$$\left(\sqrt{2\pi x}\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)\right)^{\ln x}$$

(5)  Since this value appears to grow slower than $x$, the function is decreasing.

(6)  To confirm that it is decreasing, I would then take the derivative of $g(x)$ and show that it is less than $0$.

(7)  I am not clear how to establish that it has a limit or estimate what that limit is.

Any tips or suggestions for correcting this argument and showing that there is a limit or there is not a limit would be very helpful.

Comment: could you please tell me the origin of the problem?

Comment: On point (1), I don't understand how you conclude that $\dfrac{\ln x}{x \ln x - 1.25506x}$ is decreasing. Based on your arguments, the conclusion should only be $\dfrac{\ln x}{x \ln x - 1.25506x} <1$.

Comment: Sure.  I am trying to understand when the following inequality is true:

${x \choose n} > \dfrac{x!}{(x -\pi(x))!}$  It was suggested in a previous question that I use the gamma function (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3664537/48606))

Comment: Use the facts that $$\Gamma (x + 1) = \sqrt {2\pi x} \left( {\frac{x}{e}} \right)^x \left( {1 + O\!\left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right)} \right)
$$ and $$
\left( {1 + O\!\left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right)} \right)^{\frac{{\log x}}{{x\log x - cx}}}  = 1 + O\!\left( {\frac{1}{x}\frac{{\log x}}{{x\log x - cx}}} \right) = 1 + O\!\left( {\frac{1}{{x^2 }}} \right).$$

Comment: Thanks, Gary!  That really helps!  :-)

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, my assumption here is that as $x$ increases the ratio will get smaller since $x \ln x - 1.25506x$ increases at a faster rate than $\ln x$.  Am I wrong?  BTW, your web site looks great!

Comment: @LarryFreeman I think that the fact that the map is decreasing is correct. What I'm saying is that the arguments you mention are not the appropriate ones to get the conclusion. At the end, this is a detail vs. what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks @mathcounterexamples.net!  I will work on it and update the reasoning to be more relevant.